# Multi Array filter based on another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, array-filter

I have a multi-array (arr1) and an arrey (arr2)

```
var arr1 = [["Id", "Sku", "Name"], [10, "xxx", "yyy"], [20, "aaa", "eee"]];
var arr2 = ["Id", "Name"];
```

I would like that when the values in arr1[0] is not an element of the arr2 all the index value will be removed, so I will get this output:

```
var arr3 =  if arr1[0] = arr2 
console.log(arr3); // [["Id", "Name"], [10, "yyy"], [20, "eee"]];
```

Any help?

Comment: Use `.map()` and `.filter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build a list of the indexes to remove by seeing if the key exists in `arr2`. Then, return `arr1` with those indexes filtered out of each element.

```
function filterUnusedElement(inputElement) {
  const indexesToRemove = inputElement.reduce((acc, val, index) => arr2.includes(val) ? acc : [...acc, index], []);
  return arr1.map(i => i.filter((_,index) => !indexesToRemove.includes(index)));
}
```

```
console.log(filterUnusedElement(arr1[0]));
// [["Id", "Name"], [10, "yyy"], [20, "eee"]]
```